# css property recognized only in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

As always, there is something that works in FF but does not work correctly in IE. So my question is the following: is there a way to insert class properties in `css` that are recognized only by Internet Explorer 8.

```
.style1, .style2 .style3 {
   height: 20px;
}
```

I want the `height` property to be visible only for Internet Explorer (I use version 8) because the height appears properly in FF, but if I would insert the `height: 20px` for both browsers then in FF it would be too much, so I only need this in IE.
Is there a way to do it?

Comment: `.style1, .style2, .style3` you're missing a comma there.

Comment: No I am not missing it, that is how it should be. (that's the way it is in the jqGrid css file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by others, conditional stylesheets are commonly used to target specific versions of IE.

I have recently moved over to a more efficient and tidy way of managing conditional styles which cuts down on the number of separate stylesheets and allows you to put your conditional styles into your main stylesheet. For example, you could achieve what you are trying to do like so:

In your web page(s):

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>  <body class="ie ie6 lte9 lte8 lte7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>     <body class="ie ie7 lte9 lte8 lte7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>     <body class="ie ie8 lte9 lte8">      <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>     <body class="ie ie9 lte9">           <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]>  <body class="ie">                    <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--> <body> <!--<![endif]-->
```

In your stylesheet:

```
.ie8 .style1, .ie8 .style2 .i8 .style3 {
   height: 20px;
}
```

Paul Irish and others have plenty documentation and test cases for this method. Here's a good starting point: http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/

Answer (score 2):

Not directly in the css, no. But you can use [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) in your html page to load css stylesheets only if the browser is IE, or a specific version of IE:

```
<!--[if ie]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/ie-stylesheet.css" />
<![end if]-->
```

You can also target this to specific versions of IE, with:

#### IE 8 only

```
<!--[if ie 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/ie-stylesheet.css" />
<![end if]-->
```

#### IE versions greater than IE 7

```
<!--[if gt ie 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/ie-stylesheet.css" />
<![end if]-->
```

#### IE versions greater than, or equal to, IE 7

```
<!--[if gte ie 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/ie-stylesheet.css" />
<![end if]-->
```

#### IE versions less than 8

```
<!--[if lt ie 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/ie-stylesheet.css" />
<![end if]-->
```

#### IE versions less than, or equal to, 8

```
<!--[if lte ie]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/ie-stylesheet.css" />
<![end if]-->
```

Comment: I don't remember exaclty, but it seems to me that if I comment out something with /* */ or something like this then either FF or IE would recognize it...but I am not sure of this...I was wondering if anybody knows about it....

Comment: @Atticus: there are various hacks that include things like the [star-html](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Star_Html_Hack) hack which you may mean (but the word 'hack' should give you a clue that it relies on non-standard behaviour). All css-capable browsers will recognise the `/* ... */` syntax, that's because that would be a css comment. Anything between the `/*` and `*/` will be ignored by the browser.

Comment: @down-voter, I don't *mind* being down-voted, but I would appreciate a comment explaining in what way my answer is unhelpful or in error. =/

Answer (score 0):

This is what [IE Conditional Comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) are there for :)

To make some style work only in IE, you would do:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css">
  /* styles for the IE */
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Or you can create a seperate stylesheet for IE and import like this:

```
<!--[if IE]>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="iecss.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

---

> Conditional comments only work in
>   Explorer on Windows, and are thus
>   excellently suited to give special
>   instructions meant only for Explorer
>   on Windows. They are supported from
>   Explorer 5 onwards, and it is even
>   possible to distinguish between 5.0,
>   5.5 and 6.0.

[More inforamtion](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

[`How to create IE-Only StyleSheet`](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/)